# Mongoengine how to retrieve filtered subdocuments in an EmbeddedDocumentListField in a collection

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoengine

I have a document model as follows:

```
class MyDocumentModel(DynamicDocument):
    subdocuments = EmbeddedDocumentListField(MySubdocumentModel)

class MySubdocumentModel(EmbeddedDocument):
    some_field = StringField()
```

What I want to be able to do is get a list of all `MySubdocumentModel` embedded documents contained in `MyDocumentModel` documents in the entire collection by filtering `subdocuments` on `some_field`. Does anyone know if this is possible/how to accomplish this in `mongoengine`? My research up to this point has not yielded anything that has worked.

Things I've tried:

```
MyDocumentModel.objects(subdocuments__some_field="my_field_value")
MyDocumentModel.objects(subdocuments__match={"some_field": "my_field_value"})
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With some additional searching and experimenting, I found you can do this:

```
subdocs = MyDocumentModel._get_collection().aggregate([
            {"$unwind": "$subdocuments"},
            {"$match": {'subdocuments.some_field':'my_field_value'}}
          ])
```

I hope this helps others who need to do something similar.